# EhCache dirty updates while replication

Tags: java, multithreading, replication, ehcache

I am using EhCache's [RMI](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/replication/rmi-replicated-caching.html) synchronous replication to replicate the cache across 4 managed servers.

I am not able to solve how to handle following situation - suppose my node 1 has received an update (lets says `google=$100`) for an existing element (`google`) present in cache, so it updates the element in its server cache and starts replicating across node 2, 3 and 4. Now, before replication could start or reach at node 3, node 3 receives another update `google=$103` for same element. So, node3 updates its server cache and starts replication across other nodes - node1, 2 and 4. Now, since EhCache uses read-write lock, so even if the replication started by node 1 (for `google=$100`) reaches node 3, it will wait for `google=$103` update to complete at node3, and then `google=$100` will be replicated at node 3.

So, essentially node 3 ended up with dirty update because latest value is `google=$103` but it will hold `google=$100`.

My guess is that this issue will only be with node 3 (*or any node which has received another update for same element before the last update could be replicated across all the nodes*) because for node 2 and node 4, first `google=$100` will be replicated and then `google=$103` will be replicated so they will hold the latest value/update.

I read about `BlockingCache` and `SelfPopulatingCache` of EhCache but it doesn't solve this problem either.

Anybody any idea on this or faced this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is the one of consistency in distributed systems.

Ehcache replication does not answer that problem at all and is racy in way more situations than the one you describe.

If you need proper consistency, you will need to move to clustering, which can be achieved with [Terracotta](http://terracotta.org/downloads/open-source/catalog).

Note: I work on Ehcache and Terracotta.